# How add OAuthIntrospectionConstants.ClientAuthenticationMethods.ClientSecretPost to configuration.IntrospectionEndpointAuthMethodsSupported

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, introspection

I tried to get first branch of expression in the method GetIntrospectionPayloadAsync (AspNet.Security.OAuth.Introspection\OAuthIntrospectionHandler.cs, https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Extensions/blob/dev/src/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Introspection/OAuthIntrospectionHandler.cs) but my PDB contain only second case.
As I understand, I should *add ClientSecretPost* in *IntrospectionEndpointAuthMethodsSupported*, but can't find where I should do it. (use Core 1.0)

Could you please explain where I should add this option?

```
// If the introspection endpoint provided by the authorization server supports
            // client_secret_post, flow the client credentials as regular OAuth2 parameters.
            // See https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-discovery-05#section-2
            // and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-2.3.1 for more information.
            if (configuration.IntrospectionEndpointAuthMethodsSupported.Contains(OAuthIntrospectionConstants.ClientAuthenticationMethods.ClientSecretPost))
            {
                parameters[OAuthIntrospectionConstants.Parameters.ClientId] = Options.ClientId;
                parameters[OAuthIntrospectionConstants.Parameters.ClientSecret] = Options.ClientSecret;
            }

            // Otherwise, assume the authorization server only supports basic authentication,
            // as it's the only authentication method required by the OAuth2 specification.
            // See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-2.3.1 for more information.
            else
            {
                var credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{Options.ClientId}:{Options.ClientSecret}"));

                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(OAuthIntrospectionConstants.Schemes.Basic, credentials);
            }
```

[image]

**UPD**
authorization service startup:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectServer(options =>{
                options.Provider = new AuthorizationProvider();

                options.TokenEndpointPath = "/connect/token";
                options.LogoutEndpointPath = "/connect/logout";
                options.UserinfoEndpointPath = "/connect/userinfo";
                options.IntrospectionEndpointPath = "/connect/introspect";
                options.RevocationEndpointPath = "/connect/revoke";

                options.ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = openIdOptions.Value.ApplicationCanDisplayErrors;
                options.AllowInsecureHttp = openIdOptions.Value.AllowInsecureHttp;
                options.AccessTokenLifetime = openIdOptions.Value.AccessTokenLifetime;
```

stratup api:

```
branch.UseOAuthIntrospection(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = openIdConnectOptions.Value.ClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = openIdConnectOptions.Value.ClientSecret;
                options.Authority = openIdConnectOptions.Value.Authority;
                options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
                options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`introspection_endpoint_auth_methods_supported` is returned by the authorization server as part of the discovery document (assuming it supports the OAuth2 discovery draft).

This property is supported by both the aspnet-contrib OpenID Connect server middleware and OpenIddict.

If your authorization server doesn't support this property, you can configure the introspection handler not to use discovery and force it to use the static configuration of your choice:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = OAuthIntrospectionDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})

.AddOAuthIntrospection(options =>
{
    options.Audiences.Add("resource-server-1");
    options.ClientId = "resource-server-1";
    options.ClientSecret = "846B62D0-DEF9-4215-A99D-86E6B8DAB342";
    options.Configuration = new OAuthIntrospectionConfiguration
    {
        IntrospectionEndpoint = "http://localhost:12345/connect/introspect",
        IntrospectionEndpointAuthMethodsSupported =
        {
            OAuthIntrospectionConstants.ClientAuthenticationMethods.ClientSecretBasic,
            OAuthIntrospectionConstants.ClientAuthenticationMethods.ClientSecretPost
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain that I should to add to authorization service for supporting `introspection_endpoint_auth_methods_supported` property? As I understand, it is more correct to modify auth service. Added in post part of authorization service.

Comment: The aspnet-contrib authorization server natively supports this property and you don't have to configure anything to make the discovery endpoint return it. What's the exact version you're using?

Comment: "AspNet.Security.OAuth.Introspection": "1.0.0-alpha2-final".

Comment: I meant the authorization server package.

Comment: Maybe I missed smt, but I use self-written authorization server which base on AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server (1.0.0.0) and AspNetCore.Mvc (1.0.0.0)

Comment: After checking, client_secret_post support was added in the 1.0.0-beta1 version of the introspection package: https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Extensions/commit/58a0c83b9e728ffef94421f4af172ca1a2b3c355. You're using a completely obsolete and unsupported version. Migrate to the latest stable version and it should work.

Comment: Yeh, update helped. I got new error, but seems it's not directly related with that. Thanks!